# Is there a way to select normalized data where a value IS NOT present

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have a table from Wordpress, wp_commentmeta, where I try to allow users to like comments. It looks like this

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| meta_id | comment_id | meta_key              | meta_value          |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|      23 |          6 | like                  | 2                   |
|      31 |          8 | like                  | 1                   |
|      32 |          6 | like                  | 1                   |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

I know how to get what comments are liked by user 2

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_commentmeta` WHERE meta_key="like" AND meta_value=2
```

But what I want to know is; Is it possible to build a select statement so that I get only comments NOT liked by user 2 so that the output looks like the following?

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| meta_id | comment_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
|      31 |          8 | like     |  -         |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_commentmeta` WHERE meta_key="like" AND meta_value<>2  OR meta_value IS NULL?

Comment: @sidux . . . That is incorrect.  That will choose comment 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select comment_id
from wp_commentmeta
where meta_key = 'like'
group by comment_id
having sum(meta_value = 2) = 0;
```

The `sum()` in the `having` clause counts the number of likes where the user is `2`.  The `= 0` says that there are none.

Note:  This will only select comments that are *liked* but not liked by 2.  If you also want comments that are never liked, then you need a list of comments somehow.  Your question doesn't have enough information for this variation.

Comment: Thanks! Your query is somewhat faster than sidux' alternative. My plan was to have every comment liked by the owner to make it selectable, but if I could give you some more info to allow the query to get unliked comments, it would be even more awesome.

Comment: @JonRamvi . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with aggregates, but most probably it will work slower. This is an example with NOT EXISTS

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    wp_commentmeta c
 WHERE
    meta_key = "like"
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT
                        1
                     FROM
                        wp_commentmeta c1
                     WHERE
                        c1.metavalue = 2
                        AND c1.comment_id = c.comment_id
                        AND meta_key = "like" )
```